# How to place a a Shaded Line After DIV Tag in a HTML Page

Tags: html, css

Please see my image here:

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=10ca264

After placing the chart, my code starts like this as shown below

```
<label style="font-weight: bold;">Select Period</label>
```

My question is, as you can see from the image, after placing the chart, there is a line inserted.

Please tell me how to keep this line.

Comment: You **must** use the formatting tools if you want anyone to be able to see HTML code snippets on StackOverflow.

Comment: You *may* consult [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) for definitions of *must*, *may*, and *should*.

Comment: @harpo What's your point? StackOverflow's view rendering will not display HTML code in questions unless escaped properly. Hence the emphasis. Not everyone wants/knows to hit the edit button to see what's missing.

Comment: @harpo Heh. No offense taken. Though I suppose it sounds like I did. Didn't though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<hr />
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

Comment: I want to insert a line , not a empty  space line

Comment: That's HTML. He tagged this CSS. I don't think he wants another element there.

Comment: Doh, sorry wrong tag.  It's tagged CSS, but that doesn't mean other answers are inappropriate.  Especially considering the question title ends with "in a HTML Page".  It's completely semantically appropriate to place an HTML element in this case.

Comment: Thank you Kon , that will be  perfect

Comment: Simple and Perfect answer @Kon. Sometimes we don't even guess how simple elements do great jobs.

Answer (score 0):

use `<hr/>` tag.

see here the [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_hr_test)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you're trying to add the "line," it should be as simple as specifying a `border-bottom` rule on the element you want the line on. Here's a good reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-bottom